# Are inner enums or class efficient?

Tags: java, performance, enums, inner-classes

Quite often I see people using inner enums, for example:

```java
public class Person {
  enum Gender {
    MALE,
    FEMALE,
    OTHER
  }
  ...
}
```

I am unsure how it works internally, so I am wondering whether there will be new instances of this enum class each time someone creates a new person, such as `new Person()`?

Will the inner enum keep costing more memory or will there only be a single one?

---

Follow up:
Just have a quick test on the accepted answer in code editor(Java 11):

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    int Age;
    Address address = new Address();//Usual way we see
    public class Address {
        String city;
        String Country;
        int number;
    }
}

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var a = new Person.Address();//complains "innerclass.Person' is not an enclosing class, make Address Static"
        var p = new Person();
        var a1 = p.new Address();//correct syntax to create inner clas object outside its outer class
    }
}
```

TBH, never expect such weird syntax of creating an inner class object. But considering we usually just use it in the outer class like how iterator is used in different data structure, it still makes sense that I feel strange about this.
Finally, inner class object are created based on the actual needs and dependency on the outer class, so there is no efficiency issue

---

Regarding discussion between @Zabuzard and @user207421, both make a good point. user207421 points out that class is considered inner only when they are non-static. Enum and Record by nature are static: [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3). It is good to learn from the root. But I do appreciate how Zabuzard explains everything in a way we can easily understand from scratch.

Comment: Enum values are singletons. They are only created once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Explanation

Nested enums are essentially **static** nested classes. They do not belong to instances of the outer class.

Regardless of how many persons you create, you will always only have a **single** `enum Gender` floating around, thats it.

Same goes for its values, there are only 3 values of this enum - regardless of how many persons you create.

### Inner classes

However, even if you have an inner (non-static) class, such as

```java
class A {
  class B { ... }
  ...
}
```

You will only have a single class `B` *in memory* (as you worded it). There is essentially always just a single class.

Now, when you create instances of `B`, you will have to create them based on a previously created instance of `A`, since instances of `B` now belong to instances of `A` and can only exist within their context.

Therefore, they also share non-static properties of that particular `A` instance. You will often see that being used for `Iterator` implementations of data-structures.

### Static nested vs decoupled

If you have a static nested class, such as

```java
class A {
  static class B { ... }
}
```

you might ask what the only real difference to actually fully decoupling them, as in

```java
class A { ... }
class B { ... }
```

would be that the nesting makes clear that they somehow belong to each other, topic-wise. An example would be the `Entry` class in `Map`.

---

### Notes on efficiency

You should actually stop bothering about *efficiency* on those minor things. Instead, think about **readability** for readers.

Efficiency, in the way you have in mind, is **rarely ever a factor**. And if, usually only in a **very small spot** in the whole code base (which is usually identified using a profiler).

So basically, unless you have a really good reason to not, always **strive for** the **most readable** and understandable solution.

Comment: ['Static inner' is a contradiction in terms.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) 'For former, each time you do new A(), this specific instance of A has its own instance': no it doesn't, not with the code shown.

Comment: So basically, can I understand class data is meta data of object -- template. We always have only one in memory. It is just that inner class might reference outer class(No such thing for static class)so that we have to create class A as context before B. Is my description correct?

Comment: @StanPeng Sounds about right, yes.